# INSERT INTO SELECT mysql is trying to insert different data from the selected ones

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been messing around with MySQL lately and I can't resolve one problem.

Having 2 tables.

- status_graf(id,date,time,number of players online)
- status_statistika(id,date,min,avg,max)

First one is storing data about online players every 5 minutes, second one is for daily statistics. It's separated, so I don't have to run crazy selects whenever man wants to see min,avg,max online players for last month for example.

This query works, result is a table with dates that haven't been in status_statistika yet.

```
SELECT date,MIN(playersonline),AVG(playersonline),MAX(playersonline) 
    FROM status_graf 
    GROUP BY date 
    HAVING date NOT IN (
        SELECT date 
        FROM status_statistika 
        GROUP BY date
    )
```

But when I try this

```
INSERT INTO status_statistika (
    SELECT date,MIN(playersonline),AVG(playersonline),MAX(playersonline) 
    FROM status_graf 
    GROUP BY date 
    HAVING date NOT IN (
        SELECT date 
        FROM status_statistika 
        GROUP BY date
    )
    );
```

it does not.

Using phpMyAdmin 4.3.8, MySQL 5.5.41 and it throws error #1062 - Duplicate entry '2015-01-29' for key 'date'.

Ideas?

SOLUTION:
Since the dot convention somehow didn't accept it, I had to rename column 'date' in one table to 'day' and then it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have unique index on the date column in the status_statistika table.

Comment: yep, CREATE TABLE status_statistika(
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE (date)
 ); But why is that a problem? The dates are unique

Comment: ok, the problem was naming. Too many times 'date'. When I removed unique key, it inserted always the latest date for every row - which broke the rule of being unique. Thanks man:)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO status_statistika (
    SELECT DISTINCT date,MIN(playersonline),AVG(playersonline),MAX(playersonline) 
    FROM status_graf 
    GROUP BY date 
    HAVING date NOT IN (
        SELECT date 
        FROM status_statistika 
        GROUP BY date
    )
    );
```

Notice the 'DISTINCT'